# Excel VBA Copy Cell Color error

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple function to copy the background color of cells with similar contents in different ranges (one range is failRange the other is toColor)

It fails at the line assigning the Interior.Color and the excel debugger gives me no information at all, it just stops. I have separated out ever variable so I can easily see all values using the debugger and they are all set just fine.

Does anyone see the problem???

```
        Function ColorRange(failRange As Range, toColor As Range)
        Dim targetCell As Range
        Dim failCell As Range
        Dim targetValue As String
        Dim failValue As String
        Dim colorValue As Long
        Dim compareResult As Integer
        Dim counter As Integer

        For Each targetCell In toColor
            targetValue = Left(targetCell.Text, 7)

            For Each failCell In failRange
                failValue = failCell.Text
                compareResult = InStr(failValue, targetValue)
                If compareResult > 0 Then
                     colorValue = failCell.Interior.ColorIndex
                     rem next line causes failure
                     targetCell.Interior.ColorIndex = colorValue
                     counter = counter + 1
                     Exit For
                End If
            Next failCell

        Next targetCell
        ColorRange= counter
        End Function
```

Comment: how do you use this function? As UDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **UDF** called from a worksheet cell can only return a value to that cell.  It cannot affect any cell's format.

If you want to change formats, use a **sub.**

Comment: thanks, i dont use VBA much and thought it had to be something simple like this....

Comment: You are very welcome!  If you use **c** or **c++** or **c#** a lot, the limitations of **VBA** functions can be frustrating.